# Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded in curl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am trying to write a c++ program which uses curl library to perform action(creating VM etc) on Red Hat Enterprise Virtualizatio (RHEV). I am using CURL handler to perform a post action (creating VM).

```
CURL *curl;

struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; // init to NULL is important

curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/xml");
curl_slist_append( headers, "Content-Type: application/xml");

/* get a curl handle */
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

But when I run this code I get

```
HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type
Cannot consume content type
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

I checked with the debugger even if I am setting content-type as xml it is coming as

```
0087: Accept: */*
0094: Content-Length: 173
00a9: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Could someone help me figure out what is happening? Great thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When you pass `headers` to `curl_easy_setopt`, it still is a null pointer (i.e. the empty list) and thus your header lines will not be part of your request!

The function `curl_slist_append`, in your case the two calls

```
curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/xml");
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/xml");
```

**returns a pointer to the new list** which you should assign to your list variable, here `headers`. This function basically constructs a linked list backwards from the tail to the front. [Please consult the documentation of the function, especially have a look at the example code.](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_slist_append.html)

So adding `headers =` in front of your two calls to `curl_slist_append` should fix the problem:

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/xml");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/xml");
```

Comment: A fair follow-up question would be: why this funny API? And the truth is that it was never a good API but it sort of got there by accident and we've stuck with it since in order to not break any old applications..

Comment: @DanielStenberg Totally agree. And indeed, backward compatibility are often the major reason for ugly library APIs ;) (Best example is PHP!) I didn't even know how curl handles linked lists, but I saw that it doesn't make sense to only pass a null pointer to a C function (which can't modify it since C doesn't have references). Then I simply read the documentation and found the error in 2 secs by looking at the example. ;)